# lightning-navigation stopped working post summer 20 release

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

We are using lightning navigation module in Lightning Web Component to navigate to a page. This was working fine before summer'20 Salesforce release but it stopped working post release.

```
   Reset(event) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: 'Product_Creation',
            },
        });
    }
```

Anybody else facing the same issue? Or something changes in navigation module which i am not aware of?

Comment: it is working for me

Comment: Share your full code that we can replicate it any org.if this was an issue then I think someone would have found it! We have sample apps that use these navigation service including our lwc recipes app

Comment: mine also works fine but mine is `standard__recordPage`